# CQ5 DAM virtual repository

Tags: adobe, aem, dam

I want to mount a shared drive as a virtual repository which can be used as a DAM server/location in my author instance. I read about integrating sharepoint server using the sharepoint connector. But I want to know whether I can mount a network drive or a local file system folder as a virtual repository and store all my digital assets in that virtual repository.

I am using CQ v5.6.1

Any help or pointer are appreciated, Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution here - http://goo.gl/EkTJ2k

> There are two ways to achieve what you are looking to do and they both have the benefits and downsides.
>
> The first way to do this is to use a sym link to point the standard data store location to your network location. So for example the standard location is {cqinstall}/crx-quickstart/repository/repository/datastore. So you shutdown your instance, back it up, and then move {cqinstall}/crx-quickstart/repository/repository/datastore to your network location. After you move it you create a sym link {cqinstall}/crx-quickstart/repository/repository/datastore to your network location and as far as CQ is concerned nothing changed. The one downside of this maybe that depending on how your back up processes function you may run into issues. If you are already using the Cluster Data Store this is probably the only option.
>
> The other approach if you are already using the File Data Store is to change the location in repository.xml (after shutting down and copying content first).

**Update:**
Found a more helpful answer here - http://goo.gl/dQIYlP

Answer (score 0):

You can use VLT Tool.

http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/crx/current/how_to/how_to_use_the_vlttool.html

The above links explains well how to mount up the DAM server.